# Play game background music with iPod music using CocosDenshion

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, avaudioplayer

As you can suggest, I have a trouble =)

In the game I use CocosDenshion for playing both background music and sound effects. As far as I know and can see in the code, it uses AVAudioPlayer to play background music. The trouble is appeared when I try to launch my app with music from iPod library.

I set audio category to AmbientSound (tried setting both with AVAudioSession and C interface). If I then try to play game background track directly using AVAudioPlayer, it plays with iPod music in background without problems. But if try to play background music with SimpleAudioEngine, only iPod music is playing.

Can someone give an advice how to make CocosDenshion work in this case?